# What directories inside the IntelliJ config directory can safely be excluded from backups?

Tags: intellij-idea

I create daily incremental backups of my home dir and I noticed that each snapshot contains a lot of new files that come from `.IntelliJIdea2016.2/` which is the config directory of *IntelliJ Idea*.

I already excluded `.IntelliJIdea2016.2/system/caches/*` but there is a lot more coming from other sub-directories of `.IntelliJIdea2016.2`.

Does anyone know which sub-directories beside `caches/` are save for exclusion?